# Batch File Delimiter Unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\Desktop\Pipe Delimiter Project"
SET "destdir=C:\Users\Desktop\Pipe Delimiter Project"
(
 FOR /f "tokens=1-7delims=|" %%a IN ('TYPE "%sourcedir%\test.txt"') DO (
 ECHO(^|%%a^|%%b^|%%c^|%%d^|%%e^|%%f^|%%g^|
 )
)>%destdir%\newfile.txt
```

I get the error: Delimiter was unexpected at this time...

I read about Delayed expansion, not sure if that's playing a role because I'm not assigning variables...also read about other questions that are similar, but I'm not sure why it's not reading the test.txt file...

that file looks like this:

```
|abc123|1*|004|**gobbligook|001|%|2014-01-01|||||||||||||
|abc123|1*|004|**gobbligook|001|%|2014-01-01|||||||||||||
|abc123|1*|004|**gobbligook|001|%|2014-01-01|||||||||||||
|abc123|1*|004|**gobbligook|001|%|2014-01-01|||||||||||||
|abc123|1*|004|**gobbligook|001|%|2014-01-01|||||||||||||
|abc123|1*|004|**gobbligook|001|%|2014-01-01|||||||||||||
|abc123|1*|004|**gobbligook|001|%|2014-01-01|||||||||||||
|abc123|1*|004|**gobbligook|001|%|2014-01-01|||||||||||||
```

I want it to trim the trailing pipes off the file

Can someone help me? Please?

Comment: It's the `%` sign. double it up in your file and run the script again and see what happens.

Comment: here: "tokens=1-7delims=|" %%a ? I added two more modulus signs to the front of it and that did not help.

Comment: I meant in the input file but that isn't right. I was testing using a string but when using an input file, it works just fine for me.

Comment: can you post your code? maybe my directory is bad? Idk...

Comment: it's something with that %%a after tokens...for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote a path containing spaces:

```
> "%destdir%\newfile.txt"
```